# jQuery EasyUI datagrid: Uncaugth typeerror when bundling is enabled

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-easyui

I am using jQuery EasyUI for one of my asp.net mvc applications. I am also using bundling.

When bundling is off jQuery EasyUI datagrid works fine. But when I turn on bundling by

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

EasyUI datagrid throws an exception:

> Uncaught type error: undefined in not a function

My script bundling code is

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundle/Scripts")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.easyui.min.js"));
```

Did anyone else face this problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: You use the `minificaton` library of `easyui` and you select to make again `minification` with the EnableOptimizations, probably something is break there.

Comment: @Aristos: MVC is supposed to recognise .min in filenames and not min them again.

Comment: Just a test, in case it is re-minning the file, change the file name to jQuery.easyui.{version}.js and see if it behaves.

Comment: The BundleTable, is not MVC, is just a library. Now I do not know if recognize that is all ready minificated. When I do minifications of jQuery, and other library like jQuery, I always turn off a lot of optimizations because is a complicate library and need special care !, or else is brokes. Now you better totally avoid to bundle the jQuery lib and include it alone.